# jQuery insertAfter ignoring parent styles

Tags: jquery, insertafter

I'm using jQuery to insert a button into a `div` that already has 2 similar  buttons. While this new button shows up with its own correct styles, the parent styling doesn't get applied to it (e.g. all `input` elements within the `div` are padded away. The 1st and 2nd elements are good, but the new one is glued to the 2nd button).

If I take the exact HTML of this new button and place it on the page all 3 buttons appear properly.

Is jQuery.insertAfter() somehow causing parent styles to be ignored? How can I fix this?

Comment: how do you apply parent styles and could you please share code snippets ?

Answer (score 0):

It should take the same style if you have added the style to child elements.

here is the demo

```js
$(function () {
    $('<input>', {type:"button", value:"3", class:"btn3"})
        .insertAfter( $(".btn2") );
});
```

```css
.parent input
{
    background:#ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
    <input type="button" value="1" class="btn1" /><input type="button" value="2" class="btn2" />
</div>
```